# How can I generate a tech drawing of two bodies sitting atop another body in FreeCAD?

Tags: cad

I recently designed a front plate with clamps in FreeCAD 0.20.2. It has side plates on two sides, which have been designed as a separate body attached to the front plate, which is itself an extrude object. Additionally, there are two clamps (each a body of its own) attached to the backside of the extrude. You can see the clamps just above the middle of this screenshot:

[image]

Generating 2D tech drawings for both the front plate, and the side plates went well, but what I still need is a 2D drawing showing the upper edge of the extrude as well as the two clamps, so that I can add dimensioning showing where the clamps are situated exactly.

As I haven't found a multi-body mode in the TechDraw feature (I can drag multiple bodies onto a drawing, but they are placed on the canvas separately), I must know how to add the top view of the whole construction to a drawing, so that I can depict the exact distance of the clamps from the edge of the front plate.

[STL file of the whole part](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15x7akBwC2YP4kpZxP6Tn6yfTi2gR-opf/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've just found a solution the trial & error way:

1. First,go to the Part view and set the 3D view of the part to the rear view.
2. Then, add a new Tech Drawing page by selecting *TechDraw* in the combobox in the menu bar and then adding a new page from the standard template *(TechDraw_PageTemplate)*.
3. In the object tree on the left, select the desired bodies (in my particular case: *Extrude* (the front panel), *Body001* (the left clamp), and *Body002* (the right clamp)). The clue is: **You can select more than one body.**
4. Now add a view with *TechDraw_View.* **Caution:** FreeCAD might place the view in a wrong position. Then you must adapt the position in the object's Properties widget.

The remainder does not differ from other tech drawings.